# Exact formulation of definition of $NP$, in relation to $R$

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, polynomial-time, nondeterminism, recursively-enumerable

One definition for $P$ is the set of all languages that have a deterministic turing machine $M$ s.t. if $x\in A$ the machine accepts in polynomial time and otherwise it rejects, also in polynomial time. There is no loops, so $P\subseteq R$.

One definition for $NP$ is having a certificate and a deterministic turing machine $N$ s.t. if $y\in B$ then there is a (polynomial size) certificate $u$ s.t. $N$ accepts $y$ and $u$ in polynomial time. What if $y\notin B$? There will be no such certificate, but are we forced to halt? Polynomial time rejection? Seems that there is no refering to this case, and it bothers me - to know what is the exact definition.

An alternative definition for $NP$ is for a language $B$ to have a non deterministic turing machine $N$ s.t. if $y\in B$ then $N$ accepts in polynomial time. What about the case $y\notin B$? Do we have any requirements? Must it halt? Polynomially? Definitions I found seem to miss it.

Having the two definitions equivalent is easy for me to see, and the problem I described is the same problem, only once for each definition.

Additionally, this problem occurs when define $NTIME$ and $NSPACE$. If the input is in the language, we will need $f(n)$ time (or space) for a non deterministic turing machine. But otherwise - if the input is not in the language - what limitations do we have, by definition, on the computation time (or space)? Must we reject? Or loop?

I am aware that classically $NP\subseteq R$ as well. Yet, this issue bothers me, so I am hoping to tidy this gap in the definitions.

**Edit:** I have read chi's answer in [Is rejecting in polynomial time required for language to be in P?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75970/is-rejecting-in-polynomial-time-required-for-language-to-be-in-p?rq=1) . However, I am unsatisfied with his answer, as running in some time limit $O(f(n))$ (polynomial or other) doesn't grant you a numerical upper bound on the number of steps! Say we have an input of size $n=20$ and we had $f(n)=n^2$, so the running time is $O(n^2)$, this can be any $c\cdot 400$, we can't count the number of steps and compare it to this!

Comment: A language is in NP if there is a nondeterministic Turing machine that *always* runs in polynomial time, and has an accepting path iff the word belongs to the language. *All* computation paths must terminate in polynomial time.

Comment: Therefore, if any computation time requires polynomial time, then both acceptance and rejection can be decided in polynomial time by using a nondeterministic TM. If that being so, what is the difference between $NP$ and $CoNP$?

Comment: We have a reference post on the definitions of P, NP and coNP.

Comment: Could you send me a link? I'd be glad to see if there is an addressing to what bothers me, in those definitions.

Comment: Actually it doesn’t mention coNP, but other questions on the network do, and are easy to find using a search engine. Here it is anyway: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard/9566#9566

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity)#Verifier-based_definition.  Better yet, consult a textbook on complexity theory.

Comment: @D.W. Just to be sure I understood that part in the Wikipedia's definition correctly. If the input $x\in A$, the nondeterminstic TM accepts in polynomial time, and (what bothers me..) if $x\notin A$, then the nondeterministic TM must reject, yet its computation time is not limited? (That does make sense, I just wanted to be sure about this point, did I understand it correctly?)

Comment: @BenicioAgüero There is no restriction when $x\notin A$ beyond what is implied by the case when $x\in A$. I will write an answer to explain this point clearly.

Comment: If there is no restriction, can we even claim $NP\subset R$? (No restriction might meen a loop, hence $NP\subset RE$ but not $NP\subset R$)

Comment: @BenicioAgüero  "There is no restriction ... beyond ...". What I meant is that there are restrictions that are implied by the definition.

Comment: Perhaps that is the core of my question: what are *all* the restrictions for $N$ in the case of $x\notin A$?

Comment: The difference between accepting and rejecting is that if you find an accepting path, then you know $x$ is in the language, whereas if you find a rejecting path, you don't know anything (you would need to know that *all* paths are rejecting to conclude that $x$ is not in the language). Thus for a problem in NP you don't necessarily have polynomial-length certificates for negative inputs. It is the opposite for coNP.

Comment: @Tassle I am aware of the definition of acceptance for nondeterminstic TM. What bothers me in regards to $NP$ is what restrictions do we have on $N$ in the case of $x\notin A$? Must $N$ reject?(loop?) If it must reject, will the rejection time be unlimited? (If it was polynomial, then in polynomial time we can reject - meaning we are in $CoNP$). It appears that many definitions tend to avoid this issue.

Comment: @BenicioAgüero $N$ can either reject or loop if $x\notin A$. On the other hand, as a different but equivalent definition of $\mathsf{NP}$, we can also require $N$ rejects in non-deterministic polynomial time if $x\notin A$. It looks like the previous definition is more popular.

Comment: @BenicioAgüero "this can be any $c\cdot 400$, we can't count the number of steps and compare it to this!" Yes, we can, since we can fix $c$ for a fixed problem $A$.

Comment: $NP\subseteq EXP\subsetneq R$. The left is due to bruteforce, the right is because bruteforce can be done in exponential time, whereas $R$ can run arbitrarily long.

Answer (score 2):

##### A definition of $\mathsf{NP}$

Definition of $\mathsf{NP}$: A decision problem $prob$ (i.e., a set of input strings) is in $\mathsf{NP}$ iff there is a deterministic Turing machine (DTM) $D$ such that for each yes-instance $x$ of $prob$, there is a certificate $(x,y)$ that is accepted by $D$ in polynomial time of $|x|$.

It is notable, as described in the question, the definition above says nothing about the behavior of $D$ for a no-instance $z$ of $prob$. In particular, it is fine if $D$ does not even halt on some $(z, w)$!

##### An equivalent definition of $\mathsf{NP}$

However, with the definition above, we have the following.

**Claim**. A decision problem $prob$ is in $\mathsf{NP}$ iff there is a DTM $E$ such that for any $(x,y)$ where $x$ is an instance of $prob$, $E$ will halt in polynomial time of $|x|$ and for each yes-instance $x$ of $prob$, $E$ accepts a certificate $(x,y)$ for some $y$.
**Proof**.
"$\impliedby$": This is trivial.
"$\implies$": By the definition above, we have a DTM $D$ such that for each yes-instance $x$ of $prob$, there is a certificate $(x,y)$ that is accepted by $D$ in $p(|x|)$ time for some polynomial $p$.
Let us can build a new TM $E$, which on input $(x,y)$ will simulate $D$ on input $(x,y)$ for at most $p(|x|)$ steps and

- when the simulated $E$ accepts $(x,y)$ as a certificate, $E$ will accept $(x,y)$ as a certificate as well,
- otherwise, if the simulation is done, $E$ will reject.

Furthermore, we require the simulation of $s$ steps, including the check of "at most $p(|x|)$ steps" at each step, takes no more than $O(s^2)$ steps. (If you are concerned that $s^2$ may not be enough, replace it with $s^k$ with a big $k$ such as $k=2+\deg(p)$.) So, $E$ runs in polynomial time of $|x|$.  $\quad\checkmark$

**Corollary**. $\mathsf{NP}\subseteq\mathsf{R}$
**Proof**. Suppose $prob\in\mathsf{NP}$. Then there is DTM $E$ such that for any $(x,y)$ where $x$ is an instance of $prob$, $E$ will halt in $p(|x|)$ time where $p(\cdot)$ is a polynomial, and for each yes-instance $x$ of $prob$, $E$ accepts a certificate $(x,y)$ for some $y$.

Let us build DTM $F$ such that upon $x$ where $x$ is an instance of $prob$, $F$ will, for every string $y$ such that $|y|\le p(|x|)$, try simulating $E$. At the end of each simulation, if the simulated $E$ accepts a certificate $(x, y)$, then $F$ accepts $x$ (and halts). If $F$ has not accepted when all simulations are done, then $F$ rejects $x$ (and halts).

Note that $F$ is a decider for $prob$.  $\quad\checkmark$

Since the number of such $y$s is $2^{O(p(|x|))}$, $F$ decides $prob$ in $2^{O(p(|x|))}*p(|x|)$ time. So we have shown that $$\mathsf{NP}\subseteq\mathsf{EXPTIME}.$$

##### More definitions of $\mathsf{NP}$

Similarly, if we define a language $B\in \mathsf{NP}$ iff there is non-deterministic Turing machine (NDTM) $N$ such that if $y\in B$ then $N$ accepts $y$ in polynomial time and if $y\notin B$ then $N$ does not accept $y$, then for each language $B\in\mathsf{NP}$, there is a NDTM $N$ that decides $B$ in (non-deterministic) polynomial time.

##### Some references

The exposition above is not very formal. For example, "certificate" is not defined in formal terms here. It should be good enough as an explanation, though.

Here are a few related posts.
[Formal definitions of $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Formal_definitions)
[What is EXPTIME?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPTIME)
[What is co-something such as $\mathsf{coNP}$ and $\mathsf{coRE}$?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1370/what-is-co-something)
[How to understand a class of languages as decision problems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124262/how-to-understand-co-mathcall-where-mathcall-is-a-class-of-languages)
[Is rejecting in polynomial time required for language to be in P?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/75970/is-rejecting-in-polynomial-time-required-for-language-to-be-in-p)

Comment: The problem that "occurs when define $\mathsf{NTIME}$ and $\mathsf{NSPACE}$" can be dealt with similarly.

Comment: Just to be clear: the difference between $D$ and $E$ is that $D$'s input is some $x$ and $E$'s input is already $(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes. If the input is not of the expected format, $D$ will reject. Ditto for $E$.